# C program reason for the output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX(a,b) (a>b?a:b);

main()
{
 int x;
 x=MAX(3+2,2+7)
 printf("%d",x);
}
```

I checked the output of this program will come 9. Why?

Comment: What have you expected so far? (A tribute to "What have you done so far?")

Comment: Please get yourself good resources books, websites, faqs to learn C. The way that you specify `main` shows that you don't have anything decent.

Answer (score 10):

Because everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

...because 9 is bigger then 5?
I'm guessing you're really asking how it works. (might want to look up Ternary operation) So...

```
#define MAX(a,b) (a>b?a:b);
```

Is a Macro, the name is MAX, it takes two values "a" and "b". How it works is if a is larger than b, a is returned, else b is returned.

In this case 3+2=5=a  and 2+7=9=b. So the macro boils down to:

```
if (5 > 9)
  return 5
else
  return 9
```

Then when your code is running you can think of the macro calls being replaced with that code:

```
void main()
{
    int x;
    if (5 > 9)
        x = 5;
    else
        x = 9;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Clearly we'll return 9, which is stored as 'x' then printed.

Does that help?

Comment: Ya thanks. I wanted to know how it worked. Does this macro definition replaces the place from where it is called?

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you're asking... The macro is like a function, in that it allows you to define some functionality outside a procedure to easily call it from any where  with in its scope. I'll update my example to show you.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define MAX(a,b) (a>b?a:b);
```

int the macro definition, the ternary if espression `?:` works this way

condition ? [value if condition is true] : [value if condition is not met]

Condition is whatever expression valid in C (thus 0 is false, everything else is true)

if Condition is met, the expression evals to the first value (the one right after the `?`), or to the second value (the one right after the `:` ) if condition is not met

Answer (score 0):

Because 2+7=9 which is bigger than 3+2=5.

Still, in general when writing that kind of macros you should be careful to enclose the parameters in parentheses in the expression that replaces the macro, to avoid the risk of someone passing an expression with operators that have lower precedence than the one you are using, thus messing up your expression.

So, normally you'll write:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b));
```